# Writing tests for Youtube Oauth Api

Tags: php, testing, oauth, youtube-api, phpunit

Could anyone tell me **how to write integration tests for Youtube API** that requires from you OAUTH token?

For instance in this package [alaouy/Youtube](https://github.com/alaouy/Youtube) the only thing needed in test class is just token. With that it is possible to write all required test for various request. However, this package uses NON-auth. This is easy because you can provide just token, and freely make requests.

When it come to Youtube OAUTH API the flow is that user is redirected to google website etc. This prevents me from writing test programatically.

How do I write tests for Youtube OUATH API without being redirected to external website? I have heard that for instance facebook provides dummy token so all the requests can have tests written programatically.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of PHP sample codes in [Youtube API samples PHP](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/php) which include OAuth authorization.

Here's a snippet found in [quickstart.php](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/quickstart.php)

```
$client = new Google_Client();
  // Set to name/location of your client_secret.json file.
  $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json');
  // Set to valid redirect URI for your project.
  $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost');
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_READONLY);
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
```